# Mat checkbox is not checked On Edit time

Tags: angular, angular-material, ionic4, angular8

At the time of edit checkbox is not set checked

```
<form>
 <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" formControlName="primary" > Make this primary </mat-checkbox>
</form>
```

firstly click on Edit Button

[image: Click on Edit Icon]

Then Open Edit Form 
(checkbox is not show selected)

[image: Edit Form Not checkbox Checked]

Answer (score 0):

*Solution for mat Checkbox Edit*

**Step# 1** **Add [checked]="myCheckBox" on mat-checkbox**

```
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" formControlName="primary" [checked]="holidaycheckbox">Make this primary</mat-checkbox>
```

**Step# 2 Delclear  myCheckBox: boolean (as a boolean)**

myCheckBox: boolean;

*and change my checkbox according to your result.*

Comment: Its didn't work ..  edit button ke click karna ke baad edit form par checked nahi aa rha haan

Comment: It will work. add [checked]="myCheckBox" on your input and and declare myCheckBox as a boolean type. and assign true or false to myCheckBox to show checkbox checked or unchecked.